# How to compute class intersection over union (IOU) for segmentaion in Python?

Tags: python

I have numpy arrays with multiple class for each image(car/person/sidewalk), how can I efficiently calculate the IOU for each class and the mean IOU for all classes?

Answer (score 0):

1.For calculating the mean IoU for all the classes, use the tf.metrics.mean_iou function from tensorflow.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean_iou

2.For calculating the IOU for individual classes, construct a confusion matrix and use the matrix to do the per class IOU calculation.

```
def confusion_matrix(eval_segm, gt_segm, **kwargs):
    merged_maps = np.bitwise_or(np.left_shift(gt_segm.astype('uint16'), 8), eval_segm.astype('uint16'))
    hist = np.bincount(np.ravel(merged_maps))
    nonzero = np.nonzero(hist)[0]
    pred, label = np.bitwise_and(255, nonzero), np.right_shift(nonzero, 8)
    class_count = np.array([pred, label]).max() + 1
    conf_matrix = np.zeros([class_count, class_count], dtype='uint64')
    conf_matrix.put(pred * class_count + label, hist[nonzero])
    return conf_matrix
```

[check this one out,its quite vague without comments but should solve your issue](https://github.com/martinkersner/py_img_seg_eval/blob/c0bf9787ebbe3e5e2c7833efe78b5b2d392afaf1/eval_segm.py)